# How to iterate over an Excel Range in PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell

This might be easy, but I am really struggling to write code that accomplishes this!

Just as a concept, I want to be able to write down a range of Excel cells in Powershell, and then iterate over each cell with a loop, and sum the value in each cell.

```
$range="A1:B2".Split(":")

$startrow= $range[0] -replace "[^0-9]" #equals 1
$startcol= $range[0] -replace "[^A-Z]" #equals "A"
$maxrow= $range[1] -replace "[^0-9]" #equals 2
$maxcol= $range[1] -replace "[^A-Z]" #equals "B"
$row = $startrow; $col = $startcol; $value = 0
while($col -le $maxcol){
$row = $startrow
    while($row -le $maxrow){
    $cellValue = [int]$ws_test.Cells.Item($row,$col).Text
    $value = $value + $cellValue
    $row++
    }
$col++
}
```

This is as far as I got. The nested while loop would work if I could convert the macros $startcol and $maxcol to integers, but I can't figure out how to do that (ex: convert "A" to 1, or "AA" to 27).

Is there another method I could look into to accomplish this? I'm pretty new to PowerShell and have been struggling with this for the last few days.

Comment: In your case, it is better to use `ForEach-Object` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the range of cells on the worksheet, then iterate over each cell in the range:

```
    Foreach ($cell in $worksheet.Range("A1:B10")) {
        # Process cell values here
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range

Comment: Thank you so much! That got me started and the solution was (very) simple. This is the final code:

`$range = "A1:B2"
$value = 0
Foreach ($cell in $ws_test.Range($range)) {
        $value = $value + ($cell.Value2 * 2)
}`

Thank you so much!